# I need data in a class - how can I get that data without creating a new class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

lets say I have a class like so.

```
var foodData = Class.create({
initialize: function() {
    this.foodType = {
        "grains" : {
            "item1" : "20",
            "item2" : "60"                   
        },             
         "liquod" : {
            "item1" : "30",
            "item2" : "90"                   
        },
_someMethod: function(){

}

});
```

In reality, the class is rather large with alot of methods. I ONLY want to access the data in the hash "foodtype". Is there a way I can go in and get that without creating a new class and reading in that way.. ala

```
var newSomething = new foodData;
    newSomething.foodType;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, your access should look like this:

```
var newSomething = new foodData();
newSomething.foodType;
```

You just need the constructor called is all.

But it would be better to create a getter for it, like this:

```
var foodData = Class.create({
  initialize: function() {
    var foodType = {
        "grains" : {
            "item1" : "20",
            "item2" : "60"                   
        },             
        "liquod" : {
            "item1" : "30",
            "item2" : "90"                   
        }
     };

     this.getFoodType = function() {
         return foodType;
     };
  },
  _someMethod: function(){

    }
});
```

That way you can prevent someone from changing it. (Although you should return a CLONE of the foodType, but this should get the point accross to the end user).

If you are having memory concerns because of the size of the data in foodType, then you can try this method that creates a static variable foodType.

```
var FoodData = (function() {
    var foodType = {
        "grains" : {
            "item1" : "20",
            "item2" : "60"                   
        },             
        "liquod" : {
            "item1" : "30",
            "item2" : "90"
        }
     };

    return new Class.create({
         initialize : function() {
         },
         getFoodType : function() {
             return foodType;
         },
         _doSomething : function() {
         }
     });
})();
```

Now no matter how many FoodData classes you create, they will each share the same data.

```
var newSomething = new FoodData();
var anotherSomething = new FoodData();
```

newSomething.getFoodType() is the same as anotherSomething.getFoodType()

```
newSomething.doSomethingToData();
```

newSomething.getFoodType() is still the same as anotherSomething.getFoodType()

Comment: I did do that, but I thought by declaring a new constructor I am effectively increasing memory size significantly. I am not?

Comment: You are creating an INSTANCE of the class.  If you don't want it to be instantiated more than once, because of memory concerns, then you need to create a singleton instead. The current method allows you to have several foodData objects each with different data inside.

Comment: There is another way to have only one copy of the data for any class you instantiate, I can outline that method too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood you, but

```
       var foodData = function() {
            var foodType = {//also private
                "grains" : {
                    "item1" : "20",
                    "item2" : "60"                   
                },             
                 "liquod" : {
                    "item1" : "30",
                    "item2" : "90"                   
                };
        var someMethod = function(){}//private
        return foodType;

        }

alert(foodData());
```

I am not really a big fan of Class/OO emulators in Mootools and jQuery, native JS is more fun in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want access to fooType and don't want to create instances of the class.  Then get rid of Class.create() all together and just create a POJO (Plain old java object) with functions in it.

```
var FoodData = {
    fooType : {
        "foobar" : {
            "foo" : "10",
            "bar" : "20"
        },
        "barfoo" : {
            "bar" : "30",
            "foo" : "40"
        }
    },
    doSomething : function () {
        // Lots of something to do
    }
};
```

Then you can use:

```
var something = FoodData;
something.fooType;
```

But everything you do to fooType or something, will effect the FoodData object as well